# Servicestack add/rename SOAP endpoint

Tags: soap, servicestack

I'm building a Servicestack project replacing an old WCF service node. There is a binary program that has an URL hardcoded on it and I'm not able to get/mainteain the source code.

It goes to an URL like "http://toto.com/boo.asmx".

I wrote the services in servicestack with ease and everything works great using the default endpoint "/soap12".

So to finish implementing the brillant Servicestack I just need to somehow add a route or rename the default soap12 endpoint so it listens to /boo.asmx

After hours of trying, inspecting code and googling, I was wondering if it is simply possible ?